# php curl 404 on same domain

Tags: php, ubuntu, webserver

I have a domain (virtual hosting) and I am making a php curl request to the same domain.

```
 $curl = curl_init('http://www.domain.co.uk/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $wsdl_string = curl_exec($curl);
```

its returning a 404, but curl works fine from the command line.

I'm assuming its because it is trying to access the address internally and not externally.

I think (from what i've read) I need to put an entry in my /etc/hosts file to prevent this.
So i'm wondering what it should be:

127.0.0.1 www.domain.co.uk
or should it be the I.P address of the domain?

Comment: Please read the followig [curl-request-to-the-same-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server)

Answer (score 1):

I commented out the:

```
#127.0.0.1 www.domain.co.uk
```

that was already in there and it started working.