# accomplish the same as AJAX using only PHP

Tags: php, ajax, http-post

I would like to be able to accomplish the same thing that I do in JS with AJAX all inside PHP.  Is this possible?

For example, consider the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/path/to/script/script.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'arg1':'arg_val',
            'oper':'get_data',
            'arg2':'arg_val_2',
            'id_number':'223'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            est_data = data[0];
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            return jqXHR['responseText'];
        }
    });
```

Inside PHP I want to do the same thing: pass a few post variables to the `script.php` and have it return the string response, which I get in the `success` function in the above code.

I did some research and I thought I should be able to do this using [http_post_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php), but I am getting this response:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 15:42:01 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) X-
>   Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 Set-Cookie:
>   53f143479d91e79747661fcf2777a0fa=5kidtm7rcdn14o33amljgg8922; path=/
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 15 Content-Type: text/html not
>   authorized.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: make sure you send the content-type as text/json

Comment: Judging from the response you got, ("not authorized." at the end) it looks like there's some authorization step you're missing.  Is there a missing session or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) with the help of [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/stream_context_create). You can also use [curl](http://php.net/curl).

Here is an example using file_get_contents:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>
      "Accept-language: en\r\n".
      "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'content'=>http_build_query(
        array(
            'arg1'=>'arg_val',
            'oper'=>'get_data',
            'arg2'=>'arg_val_2',
            'id_number'=>'223'
        ),'','&'
    )
));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$refno = file_get_contents('/path/to/script/script.php',false,$context);
$refno = json_decode($refno, true);
var_dump($refno); // juse use $refno as an array.
```

Comment: it seems just to be returns a rally long string that contains a lot of the code content of the `script.php`.  The script should return JSON string, do I need to change the `Content-type` option?

Comment: yes this method is just returning the content of the php script (target URL) and is not actually executing the script at all.  It is just getting the code content.  any ides why?

Answer (score 2):

I think curl will be your best friend in this case. You can do POST requests with it and send data, simulating a form being submitted.

Check out [this post](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).

```
$url = 'http://example.com/request.php';
$fields = array(
            'username' => urlencode($last_name),
            'password' => urlencode($first_name),
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I have substituted my URL but the server script is never called... I also found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server.  This indicates it may be hard or incorrect to use curl on scripts from your own server.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this. All you need to do is send a POST to the script using a PHP library (curl for example). There is nothing special about AJAX in regards to this, it is just written in Javascript. At the end the day it is just a HTTP response/request.