# cUrl not able to get the file from same server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch file from the same server i am running my php script in which i am cUrl to fetch it.

It does not download file and get timeout. 
I am able to get the file using same url from browser.

cUrl is able to get the file if the url is anything other than the same server.

Are their any settings i need to modify to support file download using cUrl on same server.

Appreciate your help here.

My code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file_url);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Is the server behind a firewall or NAT router? Resolving the URL might be returning the public IP, but you need to use the private IP.

Comment: Directly request the URL from your browser and see what comes up?? does that url is working or not?

Comment: The URL works, as i have mentioned. I am able to get the file from browser.

Comment: Is the "file" you are trying to fetch a script as well, and are maybe _both_ scripts using sessions? Then the open session in your download script will lock the session file, so that the second script can't access it and will wait for the lock to be released. The solution for that scenario would be calling `session_write_close` in your download script before making the HTTP request.

Comment: can you show me the url please

Comment: Actually even from the command line i am not bale to fetch the file. am not using sessions.

Comment: Sorry, i cant show the URL

Comment: Is this query related to the previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server

Answer (score 0):

try this with all parameters of curl

```
function curl_download($Url){

// is cURL installed yet?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

// create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Now set some options (most are optional)

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

// Set a referer
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

// User agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Chrome' `Copy as cURL` (open "dev tools", "Network" tab, right-click on a request) on a successfully fetched file, paste to a terminal, then execute.

If everything is fine, and you are able to get a file via curl at terminal, then there is something with headers and/or request params. If not, it's more likely that something wrong with your network configuration.

Also, check web server logs, do you even get to a web server with your script?

Are you using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or full TLD? Is browser connecting to Internet via proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is this:
Test if you are on your own server, then use a simple include for the same script:

```
    if (($ser = servername()) != $floc) {
       return(GetFileContent("$floc/$page.php"));
    } else { include "$page.php"; }
```