# 404 Not Found when cURLing same server

Tags: php, curl

I am working on HTML2PS and it was working fine on old server, moved to new server and it stopped working.

I have isolated the issue that the temp file I am accessing via CURL is not found from server, but the file can be fetched from other locations (e.g. my local machine)

This URL may not work in near future as I might delete this link.

http://www.lapchi.com/new/temp_curl.php5

Code of the link is as below

```
<form method="post">


<input type="text" name="url" value="http://www.lapchi.com/new/uploads/temp/html_pdf/503_S_b7ku0sbn1i8g8ll06ra1pth332.html" size="90" />
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
<?php


set_time_limit(8888);

if($_POST){
$url = $_POST['url'];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url ); // this file is physically exist on server
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($response === FALSE) {
    error_log(sprintf('Cannot open %s, CURL error is: %s',
            $url,
            curl_error($curl)));
    curl_close($curl);
    return null;
}

curl_close($curl);
preg_match('/^(.*?)\r\n\r\n(.*)$/s', $response, $matches);

$headers = array_slice(explode("\r\n", $matches[1]),1);
$content = $matches[2];


echo $content;

}
```

I am not sure, why the same file on same server can not be found via CURL, but others can CURL this url and this page can curl other urls

Comment: Maybe it's because you're trying to access the same domain with cURL? It doesn't make sense to cURL something that already exists on the very same server you're running the script from.

Comment: Why would you even use curl if it is on the same server and accessible via php?

Comment: HTML2PS is opensource code which uses the CURL to create PDF file, i am facing the issue that generated PDF file is showing `NOT FOUND` so I created this test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is resolved by adding `74.208.15.19 server.com www.server.com` in /etc/hosts file now it is working

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of:

> [Can I do a CURL request to the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server)

It really doesn't make sense to cURL something that already exists on your application's server.

Comment: agreed. this approach doesn't look provides any viable function.

Comment: related to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353369/html2ps-generated-pdf-file-stopped-working-after-server-tranfer-showing-not-foun HTML2PS need to run this, and I need to get PDF of the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed like this:

1. in the shell run curl http://www.lapchi.com/new/uploads/temp/html_pdf/503_S_b7ku0sbn1i8g8ll06ra1pth332.html
2. if it doesn't work, there must be something wrong with your DNS settings

Comment: make it work on the shell, then it will work in php. You might try to replace www.lapchi.com with 127.0.0.1 in your script or on the shell.

Comment: can not change it to `http://127.0.0.1/new/uploads .... .html` as it is serving virtual hosts

Comment: So what is the exact error you are getting when running the curl command in shell?

Comment: `# curl -I -L URL
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 14:16:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
` but it is resolved by adding `74.208.15.19 lapchi.com www.lapchi.com` in `/etc/hosts` file now it is working