# Get data from same server by ICalParser

Tags: php

There are two different websites on the same server "www.alpha.com" and "www.beta.com" and website on an different server "www.caesar.com".

For fetching events from the other sites to website www.alpha.com I take the events like this:

`$iCal = ICalParser::iCalReader(http://www.caesar.com/xyz.ics);`

But if I take events from the same server (www.beta.com), response is empty (different host, but the same IP).

Is there a solution to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `real` path of your file if you want to fetch data from same server.

Comment: @Mr. Engineer It is not a real file.

After found this:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server[/link]

I realized it with a helperscript on another server.

Comment: I mean use absolute path of file.

Comment: There is no absolute path

Comment: So what is `xyz.ics`?

Comment: This file was generated dynamicly by cms on static route. And I want cache this events by cli-script.