# Problem using PHP+CURL on FastCGI when server & client is on same server

Tags: php, curl, authorization, basic-authentication

I find this one very tricky, and I have spent a few hours on Stackoverflow searching.

I have made a REST API in PHP. Both server and client is on same IP, but different virtual hosts/domains on CPANEL-server.

When I run the client below from another system/IP, it connects successfully and JSON-data is returned from the API. It also works 100% when testing with Postman. But, when running the same client on the same server as the API-server, I get a 401-error.

```
my-server-url.com and my-client-url.com have same IP
```

Here is the client-script I run from https://www.my-client-url.com

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.my-server-url.com/api/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,["Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"]); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username. ":" . $password);
```

As an additional information - since I am using FastCGI, I have this in my .htaccess: CGIPassAuth On, which makes the auth-variables available in PHP.

But NOT when server+client is on the same IP ... $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] is not available.

Comment: Did you check with this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412069/can-i-do-a-curl-request-to-the-same-server ? There is clever solution / explications wich seam related.